# How to use DotNetZip

Tags: c#, 7zip

I've downloaded [DotNetZip from codeplex](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/view/68268) and I am totally lost as to what to do next.

I want to extract a `.zip` archive

I know I use something like this

```
string zipToUnpack = "C1P3SML.zip";
string unpackDirectory = "Extracted Files";
using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
{
    // here, we extract every entry, but we could extract conditionally
    // based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.  
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip1)
    {
      e.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}
```

My question is, what project do I add and/or what references do I add?

Thanks

Comment: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a reference to Ionic.Zip.dll - you do need to make sure you are using the right reference for your target framework version (silverlight, WPF etc)

Then the above code should work assuming you import the Ionic namespace

Also not sure what you mean by 'what project should I add' - you already have a project right, or is this just a test project and you need to create a new project? If so any project type will do - but the best tests are either a console app or a forms/wpf app

Comment: I had to add a project before I could use another discutils download so was wondering if i needed to do the same for this.

Comment: You can just add the reference to your current project (main project, library project etc) - it should work fine

Comment: Ya I got it working, was just explaining why I asked what project to add, thanks

Comment: I was too busy looking to add a reference to DotNetZip, didn't think to look for an use Ionic.Zip.dll

Comment: Hi @Charleh , I am unable to find the file Ionic.Zip.dll, is there a project I should compile?